# MySQL number ordering

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, numbers

Lets say I have table `numbers` with field `num` INT

Entries:

```
364
0
123
0
321
4215
12138
```

I want to sort them ASC. The thing is I want the zero to be left on the bottom.

What I want is pretty much

```
SELECT num FROM number WHERE num != 0 ORDER BY num ASC
SELECT num FROM number WHERE num = 0
```

Is this possible to be done in 1 single query somehow?

What I want to achieve is this:

```
123
321
364
4215
12138
0
0
```

I do not know if this is possible that is the reason to ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this condition in the order by clause,

```
ORDER BY (num = 0) ASC, num ASC
```

- [SQLFIddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c523/2)

or you can omit `ASC` as it by default,

```
ORDER BY (num = 0), num
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c523/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════╗
║  NUM  ║
╠═══════╣
║   123 ║
║   321 ║
║   364 ║
║  4215 ║
║ 12138 ║
║     0 ║
║     0 ║
╚═══════╝
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT num FROM number ORDER BY IF(num=0,1,0),num;
```